# Geocoder api returning single result

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoder

I need to Geocode all the branches of a chain within a country or state currently I am able to fetch a single result but I need to get the data for all the branches.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=macdonaldsIndia&key="MY-API-Key"
```

I think I am missing some extra parameters that need to be passed in the api.Please suggest if I am missing something

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro) web service. With nearby search or text search you can get up to 60 results.

For example if I search 'macdonalds India' for location 28.661898,77.227396 with radius 50km I can get 22 results. 20 results in the first page and 2 results in second page that I get using page token parameter.

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=macdonalds%20India&location=28.661898%2C77.227396&radius=50000&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?pagetoken=CpQCDwEAANFmh2yBVwmsgsOuEDlbKLLHXYhkn7WZNsstXOHBatJm_Js2MwEPSwHb16ICXzdt5PYu37NYPTr17MBdM6c0fIqjlB7V5otC-55bjde7Ns3l9igjMvu_hePMn03WXiRaeT7PQ8eoVTNAJQu0OrINTFtNNtU7xCm1p6UIGAzMm_phr_ZL955wTTPtqWq3XadfsdAgkwdrl2lQEbbYXhikwo-SrSfKoH2scOYrdJQ4y3SaPx95BKLPjAz8D_RfncXzQ4jVJeamuITQXMAjr1DbzKPFFNiCP3Yq_Ps7iUiUZRW8cSi5XB9RGjQN8zCQCTKWYwTWCdwfz8f49dKmj8GLw0mMfLwjJaE9tNaT1ZiEB8FMEhAD9pDF_U4CbEN8qFcgEJWFGhQ0qCZwK5EHNlVqGqk9hCYpHw9p0Q&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Visually it looks like

[image]

Hope this helps!